# How to specify the database schema to use for a Lavavel Pivot Table

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, pivot-table, database-schema

Is it possible to specify the Schema for a Laravel Pivot table when attaching?

We have multiple Schemas, specific schemas for each application and the public being tables that are shared between them.

Our Laravel app has a schema that it is defaulted too in the `.env` file. Reaching outside the default schema is relatively painless, just needing to explicitly set the table name.

`protected $table = "public.table_name_here";`

The issue is when we have a pivot table in the public schema, there doesn't seem to be a way to tell Laravel to look at the public schema for it.

Ex.

```
//users model
   public function roles() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Roles', 'user_role', 'userId', 'roleId')->withTimestamps();
    }
```

`$user->roles()->attach($roleId);`

will always look in the laravel schema for the `user_role`

When I add the `user_role` to the laravel schema, everything works great.

---

I've tried to specific to use the `user_role` table in public by doing the following

```
//users model
   public function roles() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Roles', 'public.user_role', 'userId', 'roleId')->withTimestamps();
    }
```

Unfortunately I haven't been able to find any resources on specifying the schema for a pivot table, so any advice on if this is possible and, if so, how would be great.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In `config/database.php` there is the key `connections.pgsql.schema`

When laravel connects to **PostgreSQL** uses this key to send this command to the server:

```php
"set search_path to {$schema}"
```

You can set this config key to a *comma separated list of schemas* that will be searched in order to find a table when you don't specify a schema for the table name.

In your case you can set this key in `config/database.php` to something like this:

```
return [
    //
    'connections' => [
        //
        'pgsql' => [
            //
            'schema' => 'laravel,public',
```

With that in place your SQL queries should be able to find the `public.user_role` table even without specifing the schema, i.e:

```php
public function roles() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Roles', 'user_role', 'userId', 'roleId')->withTimestamps();
}
```

Be aware that if you have a table `laravel.user_role` it will be found first because in the search path, as configured above, the `laravel` schema comes first, in this case just invert the order, like this:

```php
'schema' => 'public,laravel',
```